# UWP: WebView using the Mouse Forward and Backward Buttons

Tags: webview, uwp, mouse, back, forward

I'm developing a UWP-App with a WebView inside. At the WebView I want to use the forward and backward buttons of the mouse to navigate forward and backward. At default the WebView doesn't support it. (a normal browser does)

So I've found the PointerPressed Event and in this event I can check if the pointer-device is the mouse and if the pointer-properties are IsXButton1Pressed or IsXButton2Pressed. If I implement it on other usercontrols it works perfectly. But on the WebView usercontrol it doesn't work.

That's how I implemented it on other usercontrols:

```
private void Page_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);

    if(currentPoint.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        PointerPointProperties pointerProperties = currentPoint.Properties;

        if(pointerProperties.IsXButton2Pressed)
        {
            if (grd_content.Children.Count == 1 && grd_content.Children[0] is Interfaces.IWebNavigation)
            {
                Interfaces.IWebNavigation iWebNav = (Interfaces.IWebNavigation)grd_content.Children[0];

                e.Handled = iWebNav.GoForward();
            }
        }
        else if(pointerProperties.IsXButton1Pressed)
        {
            if (grd_content.Children.Count == 1 && grd_content.Children[0] is Interfaces.IWebNavigation)
            {
                Interfaces.IWebNavigation iWebNav = (Interfaces.IWebNavigation)grd_content.Children[0];

                e.Handled = iWebNav.GoBackward();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement the mouse forward and backward button on a WebView usercontrol?

Comment: Where are you getting IWebNavigation interface from? is it your custom interface? How does it relate to WebView? Seems to me problem is with that interface. WebView itself has GoForward() and GoBack() methods to navigate.

Comment: Yes it is a custom interface. It only implements a GoForward, GoBack and GoHome methode in the UserControls which contains WebViews. But that is not the problem. The Problem is, that the WebView doesn't trigger the PointerPressed event. That means that this method isn't called and so it can't be the error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, WebView will not trigger PointerPressed. Please check my answer.